# Trying to use jSoup to scrape data from a table

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jsoup

First time poster and fairly new coder, so please go easy on me.  I'm trying to use jSoup to scrape data from a table.  However, I'm having a couple problems:

1) I'm using NetBeans.  I get a "stop" error on Line 30 (Elements tds...) that says cannot find symbol symbol method getElementsByTag.  I'm confused because I thought I imported the correct package, and I use the same code a couple lines above and get no error.

2) When I run the code, I get an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mytest.JsoupTest1.main(JsoupTest1.java:26)
```

Which I thought means that a variable with a value of NULL is being used.  Did I incorrectly enter the "row" variable in my for loop above?

Here's my code.  I truly appreciate any help!

```
package mytest;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest1 {
    private static Object row;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect( "http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2015&month=0&season1=2015&ind=0&team=18&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0" ).get();
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        Element table = doc.getElementById( "LeaderBoard1_dg1_ct100" );

        Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag( "tr" );
        for( Element row:rows ) {
        }

        Elements tds = row.getElementsByTag( "td" );
        for( int i=0; i < tds.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println(tds.get(i).text());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your problem solved? If yes, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

This works.

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2015&month=0&season1=2015&ind=0&team=18&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0")
            .get();
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}

Element table = doc.getElementById("LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00");
Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
for (Element row : rows) {
    Elements tds = row.getElementsByTag("td");
    for (int i = 0; i < tds.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(tds.get(i).text());
    }
}
```

There are three problems with your code.

1. The id you are using is wrong. Instead of `LeaderBoard1_dg1_ct100` use `LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00`. You mistook the `l` for `1`.
2. The second problem is the `Object row`. No need for this one. Remove it.
3. You had the iteration of the rows outside of the `for` loop. And because you had the `Object row` variable, no compilation errors where present, thus hiding the problem.

Comment: Even if the OP does not seem to care to accept or up-vote this nice answer, I wanted to express my thanks (+1) to you for helping out newbies in that fashion. I would like to encourage the OP to do the same.

Comment: Alkis, thanks so much!  Your code worked great, and I appreciate the easy-to-understand way in which you helped me.  Thanks for your time! (and sorry for the gap in time, I thought the site would email me when someone responded, so I assumed no one did until I just logged back in, as I said, I'm a newb!)

Comment: Oh, and I tried to up-vote it; looks like I need to be on the site for longer/contribute more/do something else before my votes count.  But please know I do appreciate the help!

Comment: @NeverTooOldToLearn I'm glad I could help. Have fun.